# How do I list items grouped by category?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to learn MVC and finding a few roadblocks.

I'm trying to find a maintainable way of presenting a list of items divided by category headers.  For example:

> #### Entre
>
> Soup
>   Bread
>
> #### Main
>
> Chicken
>   Beef
>   Vegetarian
>
> #### Desert
>
> Cake
>   Ice cream

The category and the item are separate models, with the item model holding the category's ID.

I want to give these pages to someone who is familiar with HTML but not ASP.  For this reason, I want to keep the code embedded in the page to a minimum.  This is the best I have so far, but I'm not happy with having to use and check against a variable for each item.

```
@{string categoryName = null;}
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    if (item.CategoryName != categoryName)
    {
        categoryName = item.CategoryName;
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => categoryName)</td>
    </tr>
    }
    <tr><!-- Display item here --></tr>
}
```

Is there a method of nesting pages, such that I could make a parent page that loops through each category and calls a child page that loops through the items in that category?  For example, something like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
    </tr>
    @RenderChildren(item.Children);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest returning a view model that has the items pre-grouped using `GroupBy`:

```
return View(TheModel.GroupBy(item => item.Category).ToArray());
```

This view can iterate over the groups, display the header for each (`Key`) and send the items collection to a partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyModel>> 

@foreach (var grp in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">@grp.Key</th>
    </tr>

    @Html.Partial("Meals", grp.ToArray())
}
```

Then the separate partial view "Meals.cshtml" accepts an `IEnumerable` of your model type as its model.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyModel>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.Name</td>
    </tr>
}
```